# Writeint not displaying the value in EAX register

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I have written the following assembly code.
It's displaying the output of writeint as +0 
But When I put the debug point on the line before writeint and look at the registers 
I see `EAX=0000BFBE`. As per my understanding writeint should print the value of EAX
register. What could be the reason that it's showing +0?

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
var1    byte    24
var2    word    4000h
var3    dword   0FFFF0000h
Z1    dword    ?
Z2    dword    ?
Z3    dword    ?
Z4    dword    ?

.code
main proc
xor eax, eax
mov al, var1
add al, 10

xor ebx, ebx
mov bx, var2
add bx, 100

sub ax,bx
mov eax, Z1
call writeint

invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Is it case-sensitive?  You're correct that `WriteInt` should print EAX, in decimal, interpreted as an `int32_t`. http://csc.csudh.edu/mmccullough/asm/help/index.html?page=source%2Firvinelib%2Fwriteint.htm

Comment: And BTW, you could do zero extending loads with `movzx eax, byte ptr [var1]` or whatever, instead of zeroing EAX and then merging a low byte with mov to AL.  And you could `add ebx, 100` / `sub eax, ebx` so you know your difference of unsigned word vars is correctly sign-extended into 32-bit EAX, without potentially overflowing / truncating (e.g. if the result is negative). In your case, you'd get `EAX = 0xFFFFBFBE`, which would print as `-16450`.

Comment: Wait a minute, I misread that as `mov eax, 21`.  But actually you're loading a `0` from `Z1`.  Are you *sure* you saw a non-zero value in EAX while the program counter was pointing at `call writeint`, in some different version of your source where you didn't include the `mov eax, Z1`, or you set it to something else after?

Comment: Undefined memory variables are silently initialized to **0** when the program is run, but this may be not the case if it is executed in debugger. With `mov eax, Z1` you are loading `EAX` with whatever garbage happens to exist in undefined memory variable `Z1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting the breakpoint on the line before, I assume you mean that you put the breakpoint here:

```
mov eax, Z1
```

Well, it seems that this instruction didn't actually execute before pausing at the breakpoint. Here's the chain of events that lead to `eax` being `0000BFBE`:

```
xor eax, eax
mov al, var1
add al, 10
```

`mov al, var1` sets `eax` to `18h` and `18h + 10` is `22h`, so the whole of `eax` is currently `00000022h`.

```
xor ebx, ebx
mov bx, var2
add bx, 100
```

`mov bx, var2` sets `bx` to `4000h` and `4000h + 100` is `4064h`.

```
sub ax,bx
```

This calculates `22h - 4064h`, whose result is `0bfbeh` in two's complement and thus the whole of `eax` is `0000bfbeh`. This is the result you are seeing.

However, `mov eax, Z1` makes all that pretty much useless. `Z1` has been zero-initialized, so that line sets `eax` to 0 as well. Which is why `writeint` shows 0.